# How to force fge json-schema validator to throw an error on unknown keywords?

Tags: java, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I want my application to receive a Json-schema and later validate if some JSON objects comply with the schema. My problem is that, if I provide false Json-schema, I don't get an exception but just some warning in the logs. **So I either want to be thrown with an exception, or somehow take the warnings into consideration. However, the warning logs seem rather silent to me.**

I am using java and the library is the pretty much standard one for [json-schema](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator)

```
String json = "{\"a\":\"b\"};
JsonNode schema = new ObjectMapper().readTree(json);
JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault().getSyntaxValidator();

// this returns true but I want it to return false, since "a" is not a valid keyword
validator.schemaIsValid(schema); 

// this returns a waning --> the following keywords are unknown and will be ignored: [a] 
System.out.println(validator.validateSchema(schema));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to change the error threshold needed for the FGE validator to consider the validation as unsuccessful when unknown properties are provided. The following code does the work

```
void validateSchema(JsonNode schemaNode) throws JsonProcessingException {

  SyntaxValidator validator = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault().getSyntaxValidator();

  ProcessingReport report = new ListProcessingReport(null, LogLevel.INFO);
  ValueHolder<SchemaTree> holder = ValueHolder.<SchemaTree>hold("schema",
      new CanonicalSchemaTree(SchemaKey.anonymousKey(), schemaNode));

  Processor<ValueHolder<SchemaTree>, ValueHolder<SchemaTree>> processor =
    validator.getProcessor();
  report = ProcessingResult.uncheckedResult(processor, report, holder).getReport();

  if (!report.isSuccess()) {
    IllegalArgumentException ex = new IllegalArgumentException();

    for (ProcessingMessage processingMessage : report) {
      ex.addSuppressed(processingMessage.asException());
    }

    throw ex;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The meta-schema of JSON Schema ("the schema of schemas") permits additional properties, so the fge validator also does, and there is no reason why the implementation would change this restriction.

One thing you can do is downloading the meta-schema, altering it to `"additionalProperties": false` , then load this changed meta-schema using the validator and validate your own schema with it.

The draft4 meta-schema is here: http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema

Comment: Good point, thanks. However I found a different approach to my problem, which actually suits me better. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Good approach @erosb, @Llvanov. As an alternative, I was able to get the parser to validate for unknown properties by injecting the 'additionalProperties' attribute directly into the schema node.

```
((ObjectNode) schemaNode).put(
    "additionalProperties", 
    false);
```